# How do I resolve the "Unknown command 'build' " error when creating a docker development environment for Quasar?

Tags: docker, quasar-framework, yarn-v2

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@jwdobken/develop-quasar-applications-with-docker-a19c38d4a6ac) article to create a dockerized dev environment for Quasar.

I modified the Dockerfile to higher versions of Node and NginX and also added a missing quasar installation step found in the docs, final product being:

```
# develop stage
FROM node:14.18-alpine as develop-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn global add @quasar/cli
RUN yarn create quasar
COPY . .
# build stage
FROM develop-stage as build-stage
RUN yarn --production=false
RUN quasar build
# production stage
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/spa /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

During build though, I get the error:

```
Error Unknown command "build".
```

I'm suspect something's wrong with the preceding command line instructions which are

```
mkdir myproject && cd "$_"
docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/app -it node:14.18-alpine sh -c "yarn global add @vue/cli && vue init 'quasarframework/quasar-starter-kit' app"
```

But I'm not sure.

I tried replacing the portion

```
&& vue init
```

with

```
&& yarn global add @vue/cli-init
```

It made no difference to the error message.

How do I get past this?

The relevant output from the build process follows:

```
=> [build-stage 1/2] RUN yarn --production=false                                                                                                       0.9s
=> ERROR [build-stage 2/2] RUN quasar build                                                                                                            0.8s
------
> [build-stage 2/2] RUN quasar build:
#14 0.788
#14 0.791
#14 0.791  .d88888b.
#14 0.791 d88P" "Y88b
#14 0.791 888     888
#14 0.791 888     888 888  888  8888b.  .d8888b   8888b.  888d888
#14 0.791 888     888 888  888     "88b 88K          "88b 888P"
#14 0.791 888 Y8b 888 888  888 .d888888 "Y8888b. .d888888 888
#14 0.791 Y88b.Y8b88P Y88b 888 888  888      X88 888  888 888
#14 0.791  "Y888888"   "Y88888 "Y888888  88888P' "Y888888 888
#14 0.791        Y8b
#14 0.791
#14 0.791   Running @quasar/cli v1.3.2
#14 0.792
#14 0.792   Example usage
#14 0.792     $ quasar <command> <options>
#14 0.792
#14 0.792   Help for a command
#14 0.792     $ quasar <command> --help
#14 0.792     $ quasar <command> -h
#14 0.792
#14 0.792   Options
#14 0.792     --version, -v Print Quasar CLI version
#14 0.792
#14 0.792   Commands
#14 0.792     create    Create a project folder
#14 0.792     info      Display info about your machine
#14 0.792                    (and your App if in a project folder)
#14 0.792     upgrade   Check (and optionally) upgrade Quasar packages
#14 0.792                    from a Quasar project folder
#14 0.792     serve     Create an ad-hoc server on App's distributables
#14 0.792     help, -h  Displays this message
#14 0.792
#14 0.792   --------------
#14 0.792   => IMPORTANT !
#14 0.792   => Trigger this inside of a Quasar project (and npm/yarn install) for more commands.
#14 0.792   --------------
#14 0.792
#14 0.792
#14 0.792  Error Unknown command "build"
#14 0.793
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70677731/2714285)

> In default yarn package manager doesn't get dev dependencies if NODE_ENV set to production.

I fixed by replacing
`RUN yarn`
by
`RUN yarn --production=false`

Feel free to delete `node_modules` then `RUN yarn` once the build succeeded to get a lighter image!

Comment: I followed this advice but no difference. Have updated the question with the output.

Comment: Also added ENV NODE_ENV development, no difference